# Rosbridgelb: Received a message without op

Tags: ros, navigation, rosbridge, occupancy-grid, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROSBridgelb to publish "OccupancyGrid Message" from Unity to ROS. However I'm always getting the "Received a message without op" error. I made sure that there is no problem with all brackets, quotation marks, commas and periods. Any help?

A screenshot of the error can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NDKhzGVqHdwRJiR78YarVofdzoGBGIlD

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278065/rosbridgelb:-received-a-message-without-op/) by [AbbasSidaoui](https://answers.ros.org/users/31158/abbassidaoui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @AbbasSidaoui !

According to the `ROS Bridge Protocol` http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite, when sending message to ROS Bridge you have to specify the `op`  (Operation) field.

If you look at the link above, you will see the example message:

```
{ "op": "subscribe",
  "topic": "/cmd_vel",
  "type": "geometry_msgs/Twist"
}
```

In this message, the Operation is `subscribe`, which means that this ROS Bridge Client is telling ROS Bridge that he wants to subscribe to the `/cmd_vel` topic which publish messages of type `geometry_msgs/Twist`.

Looking at the error message on the picture, we can see that there is a `"op": "publish"`, so this doesn't seen to be the problem.

What I would do in this case is try to print the `"keys"` of the message to see if there is a key named `"op"` like in the example below:

```
message = { "op": "subscribe",
  "topic": "/cmd_vel",
  "type": "geometry_msgs/Twist"
}

Object.keys(message)
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbbasSidaoui](https://answers.ros.org/users/31158/abbassidaoui/) on 2017-12-25**:
Hello Ruben,
Thanks for your help! Is there any other way to check?
When trying to use "Object.Keys()", this error appears: 'Object' does not contain a definition for 'keys' .
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gWb6MtqMPPcOdOmLJZbz4TdPmRhCKn6w contains a screenshot of the function generating the msg